# Interactive Visualizations-Python backend and web front end

Tags: python, web-applications, data-visualization, web-statistics

I want to display some interactive graphs in web browser based on some statistical analysis. This is kind of having a python back end and web front end to display statistical analysis results like tables,scatter diagrams, plots etc.  I want graphs to be interactive not static images like I get in ipython notebook. I can not figureout how to do this? Any help is highly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information about my problem. I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416659/interactive-graph-visualisation) has some valuable information for me.

Comment: I've you tried any of the technologies mentioned in the question that you linked?

Comment: @Seanny123 : I have searched in the internet and found lot of resources and now I'm confused, from where to start?

Comment: Got some starting point for you.. check this .. http://www.slideshare.net/kenluck2001/data-visualization-in-pythondjango and http://vimeo.com/53063185 ... hope it hepls

Comment: @LonelySoul : Thanks!It has some valuable points!

Answer (score 3):

You can try [D3.js](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart/) to create all kind of charts in client side.If you are a Python hacker,you can use [d3py library](https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py).I am using this for generating custom charts for Financial data analysis.